# High latency on gateway-side LAN of wireless bridge

Tags: networking, tcp

I have a ptp nanobridge configuration that I use to connect to my brother in laws house one mile away in a Non Line Of Site configuration.  Signal levels are generally around -80 at 10MHz and internet is reliable 55ms latency with 3 mbps access.  I was recently asked to take down the tunnel by my brother in law because he noticed large spikes in latency when gaming (around 150ms).  I took down the tunnel and the issue has not happened again for him for 2 months (his latency has been a solid <50ms).  I have thought about it everyday since because I have been forced to accept satellite internet for now.  I was thinking that there is possibly an issue with all of the devices sharing the same vlan and therefore the same broadcast domain and the NLOS deployment of this tunnel is causing multiple retransmits at times and is therefore causing latency on every device on that subnet.  Please share some insight on if I may be on the right track with placing my nanobridge devices on a seperate vlan with access to the cable modem as a gateway or any other thoughts that may help. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvPvs.png) is a diagram of the setup. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is most likely that the high latency is due to congestion on the WAN link, either inbound, outbound, or both. The only thing you can look at is outbound congestion because you would need access to the ISP router in order to see if there is inbound congestion.

Comment: Ok thank you for the input.  I believe that there could be an issue with the cable modem because it is doing multiple things at once (modem, wireless router, management web page) and not doing any of them particularly well it seems to just be getting overwhelmed and processing traffic slower under load.  The cable company allots 2 IP addresses per client and allows customers to use another modem if they choose, so I am going to try to dedicate a modem for my wireless bridge traffic and see if that alleviates the latency. thanks again.